# Using __usercall convention in IDA with non-x86 architecture

Tags: ida, disassembly, calling-conventions

I'm working on SPARC binary in IDA Pro and need to use __usercall convention, but can't make it work. For example, I've tried to use the following function declaration to reflect the fact that the function returns result in register %o0:

```
int __usercall sub@<%o0>()
```

But it doesn't work, IDA says "Syntax error near: %". Removing the percent sign from register name also doesn't help.

Does anybody know if that's possible to use __usercall with non-x86 architectures at all?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Have you tried without the `%` or with an alternative characters such as `$`? Also, have you tried starting the debugger to inspect what the register names are? Perhaps that gives clues as to what should go there. I haven't used IDA with SPARC, but it's also possible you need to adjust the settings for the target processor to support a given register  representation.

Comment: Hello. Regarding trying the register name without "%" - that also doesn't work, and that was stated in my post. Using "$" also doesn't work (and that would be strange if that worked. SPARC specification uses "%" in register names, and IDA SPARC module follows that convention).
"Also, have you tried starting the debugger to inspect what the register names are?" - I can't do that. That's a firmware of specific embedded SPARC-based SoC, and I don't know how to connect to the device with debugger.

Comment: "it's also possible you need to adjust the settings for the target processor to support a given register representation" - There are no settings which could change register representation, and it is all right with register names in disassembly itself. That's only references to registers via __usercall what fails.

Comment: As for the debugger part, theoretically something like Qemu or generally debuggers speaking the gdbserver protocol should work fine. As for the rest, apologies. As I wrote I have not used IDA with SPARC and my last developer adventures with SPARC are also by now >10 years ago.